# Determine a polynomial P from a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Question**

Let $\alpha \neq \beta$ and consider the function

\begin{align*}
    p : \mathbb{R} & \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
    x & \mapsto \det \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \alpha & \alpha ^2 \\
    1 & \beta & \beta^2 \\
    1 & x & x^2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Show that $p$ is a polynomial different from $0$ and of order $2$ and determine the roots of $p$.

**My attempt**

We start by calculating the determinant and have that

\begin{align*}
  \det A
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \alpha & \alpha^2 \\
1 & \beta & \beta^2 \\
1 & x & x^2
\end{vmatrix}
& = 1 \cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
\beta & \beta^2 \\
x & x^2
\end{vmatrix}
- \alpha \cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \beta^2 \\
1 & x^2
\end{vmatrix}
+ \alpha^2 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & \beta \\
1 & x
\end{vmatrix}  \\
& = \beta x^2 - x \beta^2 - \alpha x^2 + \alpha \beta^2 + \alpha^2 x - \alpha^2 \beta \\
& = (\beta - \alpha)x^2 + (\alpha^2 - \beta^2)x + (\alpha \beta^2 - \alpha^2 \beta) 
\end{align*}

which gives a polynomial of order $2$ and as $\alpha \neq \beta$ it is also different from the zero polynomial. To determine its roots I have used that p is a function defined as $p : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which means that I can use the zero product property and by rewriting the determinant we have that
$$
(\beta - \alpha)x^2 + (\alpha^2 - \beta^2)x + (\alpha \beta^2 - \alpha^2 \beta)  = (\alpha - \beta)(\alpha - x)(x - \beta)
$$
which must mean that $x = \alpha$ or $x = \beta$. I tried to calculate its roots with my CAS but it does not give this solution, rather, a very complicated one. Is this approach alright?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I do know that.

Comment: This approach is OK.

Comment: Thanks for the verification! :)

Comment: Looks like a [Vandermonde determinant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)